# How to change the Persistent Cart time for Guest Users?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart, mini-cart

Magento 2 cleans up the guest cart data under 24 mins if left idle, is there any setting which can help to persist cart data for a guest user for around 90 days?

Comment: Did you already find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

To configure it, check the admin **cookie lifetime** (make sure to configure the **cookie domain**) and the `session.gc_maxlifetime`.

> Admin > Stores > General > Web > Default Cookie Settings

[image: Magento 2 Cookie lifetime]

[image: Magento 2 session maxlifetime]

Answer (score 0):

There is only setting to left cart for guest users with cookies Life time.
If you want to persist cart data for a guest user for around 90 days you will have to set cookies 90 days.
But more time for cookies are not recommended for better performance of website.